# Stripe 'Pay' button is hidden inside iframe

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, stripe-payments, vue-storefront

I have done everything according to the instructions in this [package](https://github.com/develodesign/vsf-payment-stripe/) for VueStorefront. And when I run the app, I can see the fields input card number, expire date, cvv, postal code.

But the button is hidden. Please help me to make the button visible. I`m stuck on this last step.

[image: Stripe Button in browser elements]

[image: Stripe UI]

Comment: I can see that it is set to `opacity: 0`. This probably means that it is waiting for some kind of trigger before displaying. Could you share some of your code so we can help you better?

Comment: Have you used Vue Strorefront before? It was a normal integration of above mentioned package on Vue Storefront.

Comment: Does it appear with `opacity: 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer myself. For Stripe integration in VueStrorefront, stripe pay button wont appear instead the user can click on place order button provided by VueStrorefront. Thanks for the comments anyway.